# Compile chokes on floating table. "Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>" error

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm compiling a doc and I get the following error no matter what I try.

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 4 undefined on input line 256.

<use logo.jpg> [4 <./picture4.png> <./picture4.png>]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.285 ...5cm} | p{1.25cm} | p{3.0cm} | p{4.5cm} |}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.285 ...5cm} | p{1.25cm} | p{3.0cm} | p{4.5cm} |}

? 
)
Runaway argument?

! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> Input_API.tex
```

Yes, I have googled and searched this (and other) sites for an answer to this. Snarky comments not required.

Here are my packages

```
%% Doc Class Declaration %%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=4.5cm]{geometry}


%% Additional packages to use %%
\usepackage{amscd,amsmath,amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage[TS1,OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{times}

%% These packages are symbols %%
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{dingbat}

%% Word wrap in tables %%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% Other Stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue2,citecolor=black,filecolor=black}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

I have other tex docs that are highly similar to this one that compile fine. For the life of me I cannot pinpoint the diff.

Here is the block of code just before line 256.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\framebox{\fboxrule=0.1cm{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{picture4.png}}}
\caption{blah blah blah text.}
\label{fig:Picture number Four}
\end{figure}
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
Full tabularx env for Xavier

```
\subsection{API Actions}
\smallskip
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{blue1}{grey2}
\begin{tabularx}{ | p{2.5cm} | p{1.25cm} | p{3.0cm} | p{4.5cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Action} & \textbf{(C)reate (U)pdate} & \textbf{Params} & \textbf{Comments}\\ \hline
\hiderowcolors
place\_order & CU & order\_id & Orders can be placed as though
 specific customers were driving the form.\\ \hline
submit\_order & U & order\_id & Submits the specified order. Order submit
constraints must be met (e.g. if you have "charge code" as a
 required field and the order has no "charge code",
then the API request will fail. \\ \hline
order\_purchasing\_information & U & order\_id & Updates am order's purchasing information.
The billing address, shipping address, purchase contact,
and charge code information may be set via this action. \\ \hline
user\_address &  CU & address\_id, type, user\_id & Creates or updates a user address.
If creating a new address you must supply the type and user\_id parameters,
where type is S (shipping), B (billing) or P (purchase contact).
If updating an existing address only the address\_id parameter is required. \\ \hline
primer & CU & primer\_id & \\ \hline
instrument & C & instrument\_id & \\ \hline
user & CU & user\_id & \\ \hline
lab\_group  & CU & lab\_group\_id & \\ \hline
charge\_code & CU & charge\_code\_id & \\ \hline
template & CU & tempalte\_id & \\ \hline
container\_map & U & container\_id & This action updates the location map (a two-column text string that maps container locations to template barcode) for an existing container. Useful for automatically updating the contents of a plate that was just scanned by a bed scanner. \\ \hline
inventory\_item & CU & & inventory\_item\_id \\ \hline
update\_template\_step & U & template\_id (\textit{n}-many) & Updates the step of a supplied list of tempaltes to
the next step in their workflow. \\ \hline
update\_container\_step & U & container\_id (\textit{n}-many) & Updates the step of a list of provided containers.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Seconding what Peter said, make sure to *remove all* irrelevant packages, i.e. all packages that whose inclusion isn’t necessary for the reproduction of the problem. (Also see my answer to the MWE question Peter linked to.)

Comment: On line 256 you get a *warning* not an error, so the real problem in not on that line. The first error message suggests there's something wrong with some tabular material around line 285. Please check that line.

Comment: @Peter and doncherry - While working on an MWE I discovered that the png I'm using in figure 4 may be corrupt. That could be the source of the problem. I'll keep working on a good MWE unless I solve it. Thanks for your pointers thus far.

Comment: @Gonzalo - the log output says warning, but the compiling won't progress beyond that point. So warning or not I'm calling it an error. I'm not convinced that particular warning is actually part of the problem, but seeing as how it occurs right at the point of failure I included it. Plus I noticed quite a few posts on this forum that found that a warning was actually the source of a downstream error. Thanks for your comment. I'll keep digging.

Comment: @user1883857 The compilation does seem to progress beyond that point actually. According to the log you posted, TeX issues a warning about an undefined reference on line 256, includes your file `picture4.png` on the 4th page of its about but chokes _after that_, on line 285.

Comment: Please include the *complete* `tabularx` environment that is included around the lines causing the error.

Comment: @Xavier - Added update to issue for full tabularx block.

Comment: As Werner wrote in his answer, `tabularx` requires you to provide the width of the total tabular before providing the column specifications.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the width of the `tabularx` environment - a requirement:

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{<col spec>}
%...
\end{tabularx}
```

However, you're not using any `X`-columns - the special stretchable columns within `tabularx`. So, I suggest just removing the use of `tabularx` altogether, and use a traditional `tabular`.